# Attempts to change water flow result in no flow at all

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to add a small flow of water into my pool. After following dozens of tutorials I eventually got some water coming out, but much too 'fat'.

I thought I just had to make a few changes and I would get what I wanted - a little stream of water, but every time I make any change, the size of inflow, the radius of particles,the slightest change anywhere in fact, no water comes out.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Location and Scale*, *All transforms* after any change, I have tried *Free All* and *Bake All*, but whatever I do, even moving or deleting something not in the domain, the blob of water doesn't appear any more.

Comment: Thank you for your edits.  I'll take more care next time. How can I add - upload my blend file with the question ?